# difference in static vs anonymous namespace for second pass name lookup during template instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, scope

I've *long* since stopped using `static` for helper functions in favor of an anonymous namespace, which has the advantage of working with types, variables, and templates as well as for functions.

However, I was surprised when a function was not found when I replaced a call to it with a wrapper template.  See code at https://godbolt.org/z/GrojceqGx with compiler and options that match my project.

```
#include <utility>
//#define WORKING

class C {};

template <typename Left, typename Right>
auto wrapper (Left&& left, Right&& right, const char* name)
{
    return foo (std::forward<Left>(left),std::forward<Right>(right));
}

#ifdef WORKING
static
void foo (C& left, int right)
{
    // compiles when using static function
}
#else
namespace {
void foo (C& left, int right)
{
    // fails to compile in anonymous namespace
}
}
#endif

void sample()
{
    C x;
    wrapper (x, 17, "call 1");
}
```

Why does the instantiation of `wrapper` see `foo` when it is `static` but not when it is in an anonymous namespace?  The point of instantiation is in this translation unit, in the same spot either way.

Comment: Update the directives and comment in the code to show the difference more clearly, although that does change the code in the question from that on godbolt.

Comment: Also works if you move the template declaration after the declaration of `foo` - live - https://godbolt.org/z/nbxf5nGsY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the anonymous namespace is, believe it or not, another namespace entirely. And not the global namespace.

`foo` is found by [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) when you use `static`. Because now `foo` is properly in the associated namespace of `C` (the global namespace).

It will work however for an inline anonymous namespace, i.e.

```
inline namespace { }
```

Since ADL is designed to work nice with inline namespaces.

Comment: There's more to the namespaces in the real example:  `C` is in a namespace and the global namespace in this CPP file is `using` it.  But putting `inline` did fix this issue.